# Implementing Optimistic UI in Java

Tags: java, android, optimistic-ui

So I'm reading about [Optimistic UI](https://uxplanet.org/optimistic-1000-34d9eefe4c05) and it's something I would like to implement in my android java app.

My android app connects with my rest api.  My confusion is how do I go about this?

I have a products api that I call from the android app to save data.  How do I do this using the optimistic ui approach.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way? I assume the rest API will either call a callback, or send a message some other way (like rxJava or a message bus).  Have your rest API call the callback/send the message once with the optimistic result, then again with the real result.

Remember that the problem with an optimistic result is that its a (possibly educated) guess.  It can be very wrong.  So there's places where its a viable solution, and places it isn't.  For example, a banking app shouldn't optimistically guess someone's balance. I'd say the number of places where it makes sense are dwarfed by the number it doesn't.

Comment: So if I update the UI, the user leaves the page and comes back before the save operation is completed.  How do I persist the modified data on the device?